# Azure Custom Policy B2C How I can read the employeeid of an user of Azure AD and populate a textbox with this value

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am creating a custom policy with the starterpack of azure. My problem is the next:
I need to do some change in the TrustFrameworkextensions.xml so that when the user goes to sign in for the first time, it shows on screen the value of the employeeid of the user that made the login for the user to confirm it, that is to say that a textbox appears, like the ones in the image below, with the employee number of the user in AD filled and that the user simply confirms by clicking continue. What do I have to modify or add in this file?

[image]

I don't know how I can get the value employeeid, I tried this:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>XXXXXXX</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Login using XXXXXX</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AADXXXXXX-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>XXXXXXX Employee</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your XXXXX account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">3700a22a-c43d-441d-a978-14e4abfac8c4</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_XXXXXXXXSecret"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="employeeID" /> <!--poner given_name-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_employeeid" PartnerClaimType="employeeId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
        <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_employeeid" PartnerClaimType="employeeId" /> --><!--ClaimTypeREferenceId nombre campo en b2c y parnerclaimtype nombre campo en AD-->
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [self-asserted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) technical profile that contains the three fields.

Add this to the user journey.

To pre-populate the fields, define them as input fields.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I would like to know if is possible pre-populate the field and pass it without having to show the confirmation screen?

Comment: another question, how can I collect the employeeid value of the AD user so that when the user is  registered in b2c it will be saved with that id.

Comment: Configure AAD so it passes the attribute than add "extension_employeeid" as an output in the B2C write.

Comment: I created the extension_employeeid in AAD and B2C, but the value is empty to the end of  user flow with custom policy. I don't know if I am doing good, because I need the value of Employee ID that the user has in AD when you see the profile of the user, this is the exact value that I need

Comment: It's not an extension attribute on the AAD side. Map "employeeId" on AAD as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims. Check the B2C debug logs as well if issues.

Comment: in the link you have given me, "employeeId" does not appear in the list of "add optional claims", where can I find it?

Comment: As per the link, add it via the manifest

Comment: I added employeeId in the manifest in the part of access token: "accessToken": [
   {
    "name": "employeeId",
    "source": null,
    "essential": true
   }
  ], and in Token configuration show me the message the claim is not supported and will not be returned in the token

Comment: One question, the employeeid that I are talking about is the same employeeId that we can see in the user properties in Azure AD??? If not, how could I refer to that employeeid?